# Syntax error when a job is executed in anonymous block in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to execute a job with an alter system command but I get a error. I know that the error is in `SID=''INST1''''`, but I don't know how to avoid it. 
I can create the job but the error is when the job is executed.

This is the code of the job:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'JOB_Cambia_Planes_Prueba',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 
'BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''ALTER SYSTEM SET resource_manager_plan=PLAN1 SCOPE=BOTH SID=''INST1'''';
exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);       
END;
',
   start_date           =>  TO_DATE('16-12-2019 17:33','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'),
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY', 
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'Cambiar Planes');
exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);      
END;
```

And the error is

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 89:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INST1" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
   returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
   like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk
   member submultiset
The symbol "* was inserted before "INST1" to continue.
```

Comment: A scheduler jobs runs in background, thus `dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);` seems to be useless as you will never see such message. Better remove it, in case you have an error it will be tracked in view `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit No, not useless. The output of `dbms_output` is displayed in the `OUTPUT` column in `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`. I prefer this one over having the database alert log spammed with failed job runs.

Answer (score 4):

Not enough apostrophes.

```
SQL> !cat 1.sql
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'JOB_Cambia_Planes_Prueba',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           =>
'BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''ALTER SYSTEM SET resource_manager_plan=PLAN1 SCOPE=BOTH SID=''INST1'''';
exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
',
   start_date           =>  TO_DATE('16-12-2019 17:33','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'),
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY',
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'Cambiar Planes');
exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
/

SQL> @1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('JOB_Cambia_Planes_Prueba');
BEGIN dbms_scheduler.run_job('JOB_Cambia_Planes_Prueba'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 82:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INST1" when expecting one of the following:
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk
member submultiset
The symbol "* was inserted before "INST1" to continue.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 242
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 566
ORA-06512: at line 1

SQL> exec dbms_scheduler.drop_job('JOB_Cambia_Planes_Prueba');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> !vi 2.sql

SQL> !cat 2.sql
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'JOB_Cambia_Planes_Prueba',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           =>
'BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''ALTER SYSTEM SET resource_manager_plan=PLAN1 SCOPE=BOTH SID=''''INST1'''''';
exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
',
   start_date           =>  TO_DATE('16-12-2019 17:33','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'),
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY',
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'Cambiar Planes');
exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
/

SQL> @2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('JOB_Cambia_Planes_Prueba');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

To elaborate, this value of `job_action`

```
'BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''ALTER SYSTEM SET resource_manager_plan=PLAN1 SCOPE=BOTH SID=''INST1'''';
exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
',
```

is a string literal. Obviously, string literals are delimited with single quotes (`'`). That string, however, is a script containing another string literal, the `ALTER SYSTEM` command, which must be delimited too. As you know, you escape a quotation mark inside a string by doubling it. So, the `ALTER SYSTEM` command inside the string literal must be delimited with `''` rather than `'`. This is what you have done, so far so good.

Now, the `ALTER SYSTEM` command, in its turn, also contains a string literal, namely `INST1`. This is now the second level of string nesting. You need to double the delimiters again, so `INST1` should be delimited with `''''`. In your snippet, however, it is delimited with `''`, which is wrong.

Therefore, the solution is to rewrite the `… SID=''INST1''''` bit as `… SID=''''INST1''''''`, as already illustrated above. The closing six apostrophes are the four closing apostrophes for the `INST1` value plus the two closing apostrophes for the `ALTER SYSTEM` command.